# Intertext like command in enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I would like to insert some explanatory text between two items of a numbered list.

Is there a command that can do this in the same way as the `\intertext` command in an `align` environment?

Comment: Do you think it looks nicer to indent the intertext the same amount than other items or remove the indentation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and two separate `enumerate` environments, adding `resume` as option to the second environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item of enumerated list.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}

Some explanatory text.

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly as explained in [the `enumitem` package documentation](www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf) on page 6.

Comment: It works! And it looks like I used to wrong key words for my search.

Comment: May be you can define a command: `\newcommand{\myintertext}[1]{\end{enumerate} #1\begin{enumerate}[resume]}`.

Comment: If one uses `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`with more sophisticated labels the possibility to use multiple arguments is very helpful: `\begin{enumerate}[step 1):, resume]`

Answer (score 21):

Here is a custom command, `\enumeratext`, which works like `\intertext`, it does not require `enumitem`:

```
\newcounter{saveenumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enumeratext}[1]{%
\setcounter{saveenumerate}{\value{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}
\end{enumerate}
#1
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\value{saveenumerate}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{saveenumerate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enumeratext}[1]{%
\setcounter{saveenumerate}{\value{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}}
\end{enumerate}
#1
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\value{saveenumerate}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is a list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Something,
\item some other thing,
\item and more;
\enumeratext{Some intertext}
\item let's continue,
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item here is a sublist,
        \item some stuff,
        \enumeratext{more intertext}
        \item yet another stuff.
    \end{enumerate}
\item last thing.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: Now works for lower level list.

Answer (score 10):

I achieved the task by just putting 
`\item[]` instead of `\item` in front of the inter text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is the easiest solution. Though some may prefer a non indented one, and it's not as easy as using \noindent

Answer (score 6):

Here is an analogue for `\intertext` called `\listintertext`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listintertext}{\@ifstar\listintertext@\listintertext@@}
\newcommand{\listintertext@}[1]{% \listintertext*{#1}
  \hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}#1}
\newcommand{\listintertext@@}[1]{% \listintertext{#1}
  \hspace{-\leftmargin}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item of enumerated list.

  \begin{itemize}
    \item First bullet.

    \listintertext*{Some explanatory text.}

    \item Second bullet.

    \listintertext{Some explanatory text.}

    \item Third bullet.
  \end{itemize}

  \item Second item.

  \listintertext{Some explanatory text.}

  \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The starred version `\listintertext*` always sets the text flush with the left margin, regardless of the nesting depth, while the unstarred version `\listintertext` sets the text with only the *current* list depth left margin removed.

Comment: when the explanatory text is longer than one line, the remaining lines are indented, As far as I can tell this command just applies negative space "its contents", but I cannot come up with a way to extend that to multiple lines
The reason I'm focusing on this answer is that I'm trying to use it in a custom list

Comment: @Mahoma: I'm sure one could place the content in a `\parbox` with some `\strut`s. That would allow multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

This is not necessarily better but I have used the following, due to Michel Bovani, for many years:

```
            \makeatletter
            \newcommand{\interitemtext}[1]{%
            \begin{list}{}
            {\itemindent=0mm\labelsep=0mm
            \labelwidth=0mm\leftmargin=0mm
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\@totalleftmargin}}
            \item #1
            \end{list}}
                \makeatother
```

The only improvement I have ever wished is to be able to control the vertical space above and below the interitemtext.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overkill solution using a math environment `$ ... $`:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Pre-text
    $ \text{middle text} $
    \item Post-text
\end{itemize}
```

If you want the text to be centered, use `$$` instead of `$`

Comment: Won't `$` lead to `middle text` being on the same line as `Pre-text`?

Comment: @Teepeemm By middle I meant inbetween pre and post (vertically), not horizontal alignment. Is that the question?

Comment: But I'm not seeing anything to make middle come below pre.  `$$` would do that, but `$` will just keep typing in the same line.  You'd need to force a new line (perhaps with `\\ `, but then the `$` is really doing nothing).

Comment: @Teepeemm mmm maybe because I tested it on beamer it worked. Will check.