# Is there some way to add text between the items of an enumerate or itemize environment

Tags: lists

The title says it all. This does not seem possible with a regular enumerate or itemize enviroment. Do you need to use a special/custom environment for this, or am I missing something?

I thought this might be a duplicate, but did a search and did not find anything.

Comment: Is this relevant? [Intertext like command in enumerate environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135726/intertext-like-command-in-enumerate-environment) Or are you looking for putting the same text automatically between all items?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Do the methods given in that question also work for itemize? A general solution would be good. If so, then this is a dupe of that question.

Comment: Should be (haven't tested). If not, I'll rescind my close vote.

Comment: Worst case, Harish's comment on the accepted answer should almost certainly work for any list-like environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, the `resume` or `resume*` options to enumerate or itemize environments, defined in the `enumitem` package let you interrupt temporarily such an environment to insert some text. Usage:

```
\begin{enumerate}[options…]
    ……
\end{enumerate}
 Some text…
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    ……
\end{enumerate}
```

The `resume*` option uses the options of the previous list. You may change the restarting index with `[resume, start=n]`.

The package also defines a notion of `series` of lists. See the details in § 3.4 & 3.5 of [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).