# Indent texts within an enumerated list

Tags: indentation, enumerate

What I want to is to get is the sentence **Next follows Items 3 to 6**, to be indented not with the enumerated list itself but with the normal indentation. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

This is an enumerated list.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2

Next follows Items 3 to 6

\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could end the `enumerate` before the "intertext" and `resume` it later (with `enumitem`), but that could give you too much space around the "intertext".

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
Next follows Items 3 to 6
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`

Comment: As moewe write, that text is not a part of a list, thus semantically the only right thing to do is to suspend the list and restart it afterwards. `enumitem` is a great package, but it also has its quirks, see the manual for the difference between `resume` and `resume*`

Comment: You don't have to use `enumitem` to resume your lists, there are other ways: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669/35864

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135726/35864? Should probably have searched before I wrote the answer :-(...

Comment: `\hspace*{-\leftmargin}Next follows Items 3 to 6` also works, although you will need a \parbox for more than one line.

Answer (score 1):

I would just `\end` the `enumerate` before the "intertext" and then `resume` it again afterwards. With `enumitem` you can just use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}%
Next follows Items 3 to 6
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439546/indent-texts-within-an-enumerated-list/439548#comment1103738_439546) now with `resume*` instead of `resume` to also resume the style of the previous `enumerate`.

The spacing is not too bad here I think, so you might not even have to change that.

Your MWE loads the `enumerate` package, so you will probably want to switch from `enumerate`'s syntax to `enumitem`.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

becomes

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

Or you can load `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option, which is intended to provide some compatibility with how the `enumerate` package works.

Depending on your use cases you may want to look into making these definitions global with `\setlist` or defining a new list environment with `\newlist`. For more on that see [the `enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

If you prefer not to use `enumitem`, you can have a look at [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669/35864) for alternative ways to resume your `enumerate`.

Comment: This is clashing with what I have originally, \usepackage{enumerate} for lists of the type \begin{enumerate}[(a)]..... Is there a way to resolve this ?

Comment: @Fib1123 You can either switch completely from the `enumerate` package to `enumitem` and say `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` for the first `enumerate`. Or you can use [Carl Mummert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1702/35864) to resume the `enumerate` without `enumitem`.

Comment: @Fib1123 just load enumitem with the shortlabels option, moewe do you mind adding that option to the example. Shortlabels makes it fully compatible with the syntax of the enumerate package

Comment: @daleif I have added a short statement about that at the end. Would that be enough? I think if you use `enumitem` you might as well buy into the slightly more verbose syntax.

Comment: Actually I tend to make it much less verbose by predefing se real setups such that the label key is never directly used in the manuscript. Maybe I'll add an example when I'm at a pc again

Comment: @daleif For recurring uses that or a global setting is certainly the best option.

Comment: One of the nice things about enumitem is setlist if you combine it with etoolbox, you can control list defaults on a per env basis, very useful for teaching materials, where some envs may have different setups than others.