# Problem of indent with multiple levels of enumerate

Tags: enumerate

firstly, sorry for my english, I'm French.
Secondly, I've a problem with enumerate, when I have multiple levels of enumeration. An example is better than long speeches :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Listes
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges   

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listintertext}{\@ifstar\listintertext@\listintertext@@}
\newcommand{\listintertext@}[1]{% \listintertext*{#1}
  \hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}#1}
\newcommand{\listintertext@@}[1]{% \listintertext{#1}
  \hspace{-\leftmargin}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
 \item 1.
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
  \item 1.(a)
 \end{enumerate}

Blabla

 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},resume]
  \item 2.(b)
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.}]
   \item 2.(b).i.
  \end{enumerate}

\listintertext*{blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla}

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.},resume]
   \item 2.(b).ii.
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

gives this :

[image]

My problem is now : I want long text (blabla [...] blabla) to be aligned in the left of the page, and not aligned with the enumerate item.

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: You don't need to start each of your posts with an apology for your English. It's absolutely fine as far as I am concerned. (Plus we can tell that you are from a French-speaking country by the spaces before `:` and `?` `;-)`)

Comment: Ok, thanks ;) Ah, I didn't know this is a French language speciality

Comment: Do you want it aligned with the bold 1?

Comment: Can't you just `\end` the `enumerate` before the `Blabla`? At the moment they live within the enumerate and so take its indentation.

Comment: No because if I do this, the (b) item is aligned with 1., not with (a)
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
 \item 1.
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
  \item 1.(a)
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Blabla

 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},resume]
  \item 2.(b)
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.}]
   \item 2.(b).i.
  \end{enumerate}

blabla

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.},resume]
   \item 2.(b).ii.
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

Comment: Mhhh, maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135726/35864 can help you.

Comment: I already use `resume` but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: It looks like there is an answer from @moewe 's link that addresses your problem.  See Werner's answer there.  Basically, you put `\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}` before your text.  Because it uses `@`, you need to wrap `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around it...which is why it's better to make a new command.

Comment: Ok thank you for your explanation. It does'nt work totally (see edited MWE). Am I required to adjust manually ? It would be surprising...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an environment where you set `\parshape=0`. Also some other bookkeeping is necessary; no need to break and resume the `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Listes
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges   

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakenum}
 {% issue \par as defined in a list
  % then reset it to the primitive
  \par\let\par\@@par
  % add spacing like for an item
  \vspace{\itemsep}%
  % reset \parshape to 0
  \parshape\z@
  % reset \@totalleftmargin and \linewidth
  \@totalleftmargin=\z@
  \linewidth=\columnwidth
 }
 {\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
  \item 1.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
    \item 1.(a)
  \end{enumerate}

  Blabla

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},resume]
    \item 2.(b)
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.}]
      \item 2.(b).i.

\begin{breakenum}
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\end{breakenum}

      \item 2.(b).ii.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with two environments: `breakenum*` only removes the current `\leftmargin`, whereas `breakenum` goes all the way.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Listes
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges   

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakenum}
  {\breakenum@reset{\@totalleftmargin}}
  {\par}
\newenvironment{breakenum*}
  {\breakenum@reset{\leftmargin}}
  {\par}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\newenvironment{breakenum+}
  {%
   \breakenum@reset{\leftmargin}
   \setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}%
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}% 
  }
  {\par}

\newcommand{\breakenum@reset}[1]{%
  % issue \par as defined in a list
  \par
  % add spacing like for an item
  \vspace{\itemsep}%
  % reset \@totalleftmargin and \linewidth
  \addtolength{\linewidth}{#1}%
  \addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{-#1}%
  % reset \parshape
  \parshape\@ne\@totalleftmargin\linewidth
 }
 {\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
  \item 1.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
    \item 1.(a)

\begin{breakenum*}
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla

blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\end{breakenum*}

    \item 2.(b)
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*.}]
      \item 2.(b).i.

\begin{breakenum}
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla

blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\end{breakenum}

      \item 2.(b).ii.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{breakenum+}
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla

blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
blabla
\end{breakenum+}

\item 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it works but I want :
1) to have possibility (but no obligation) to have an indentation before a new paragraph
2) in the last 'blabla' paragraph (after 2(b)i), I want the text takes all the width of the page (Am I clear ? Not sure)

Comment: @Alex I fixed the second implementation and added also a `breakenum+` environment that does normal indentation.

Comment: It works perfectly !! Thank you very much ! I just changed a little to have that I want, but it's perfect ! Thank you again !